# How to pass a list of strings to a function?

Tags: r

I have a function `lvar2` (courtesy: [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2372064/mrflick), from answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62748018/is-there-a-way-to-create-an-r-function-using-a-string-formula-with-and)),  which converts inputs into a line of characters.

```
lvar2 <- function(...) {
  params <- list(...)
 # stopifnot(length(params)%%2==0)
  lefts = "LV"
  rights = params[seq(1,length(params), by=2)]
  rights <- Map(paste, rights, collapse="+")
  paste(paste0(lefts, " =~", rights), collapse="\n")
}
```

For example

`inputs <- c("abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "mno", "pqr", "stu", "vw", "xyz")`

`lvar2(inputs)`

returns this:
`"LV =~abc+def+ghi+jkl+mno+pqr+stu+vw+xyz"`

Thanks to people's help from this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63416728/how-to-generate-a-list-of-combinations),

I have this loop function to generate a list of combinations, which i used to store into `abc`

```
library(purrr)
abc <- seq(3, length(inputs)) %>% map(combn, x = inputs, simplify = FALSE) %>% flatten
```

Now I'm trying to iterate the values in `abc` inside the `lvar2` function.

I tried this

```
for (i in abc) {
  a <- lvar2(i)
}
a
```

but I'm getting only one line of output:

```
[1] "LV =~abc+def+ghi+jkl+mno+pqr+stu+vw+xyz"
```

How can I make this right? I'm quite new to `for` loops or anything like that.

Comment: Try `lapply(abc, lvar2)`.